# Save object to RData using eval(parse(text=...)))

Tags: r

I am able to write an object to a .csv file using `eval(parse(text=...)))` but cannot save to an .RData file. Why is that? Any suggested workarounds?

```
# Assign value to variable name (in my function this variable name changes)
varName <- "test"
assign(x=varName,value=mtcars)

# Check variable exists
head(test)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

# Save .csv
write.csv(eval(parse(text = varName)), file=paste0(varName, ".csv") # works

# Save .RData
save(eval(parse(text = varName)), file=paste0(varName, ".RData")) # doesn't work

>  Error in save(eval(parse(text = varName)), file = paste0(varName, ".RData")) : 
  object ‘eval(parse(text = varName))’ not found
```

Comment: Why not use `(m)get`?

Comment: @NelsonGon can you elaborate on usage of `get` in this instance?

Comment: You can `get` varName from the environment where you assign it?

Comment: See `fortune(106)`

Comment: How about `save(list=varName, file=...)`?

Comment: @r2evans This solution worked as I had wanted, if you add the answer officially, I'll accept and mark anwered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is to use

```r
save(list = varName, file = paste0(varName, ".RData"))
```

It saves having to `get` (or `mget`) the variable(s), as `save` effectively does it for you.

Answer (score 3):

The answer,  aside from  `fortune(106)` is to investigate:  execute

`eval(parse(text = varName))`

to see what class the returned object is.  Compare with what `save` requires.

That will show, as the other comments and answer does/did that you need a character object for that argument in `save` .

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on why! Should have checked that.

Comment: Can you provide use case of `get` for this example?

Comment: @Djork  Sorry about that -- on review it's clear that `get` is not what's needed for `save` function.   There are other situations where `get` will do -- correctly -- what `eval(parse())` might achieve.